# ANTLR: ignore statements in parser

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, ebnf

I have defined the following things in ANTLR4:

```
prog: stat+ ;

stat: 
    ID '=' expr STATEMENT_TERMINATOR                            #Assignment
|   QUESTIONMARK text=STRING? expr? STATEMENT_TERMINATOR        #Print
|   ID '=' QUESTIONMARK prompt=STRING? STATEMENT_TERMINATOR     #Input
|   NEWLINE                                                     #StatementTerminator
|   STATEMENT_TERMINATOR                                        #NewLine
;
```

I wonder how I can make the parser ignore the NEWLINE and STATEMENT_TERMINATORS at the end of my program. Reason why I ask is:

I want to return the result of the last statement as the result - but if there is an additional NEWLINE or STATEMENT_TERMINATOR at the end, I get no meaningful return value.

```
-> skip
```

also doesn't work: "Reference to undefined rule 'skip'".

Can I make ANTLR ignore statements at the parser level as well?

Comment: Why do you have NEWLINE and STATEMENT_TERMINATOR among stat rules at all? I do not understand.

Comment: Can you skip the new lines in the lexer or are they significant to the language?

Comment: I'm a beginner... thats why... got it right this time. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `skip` command only for lexer rules, not parser rules. In your case I suggest to rewrite grammar by the following way:

```
prog: stat+ ;

stat: 
    ID '=' expr STATEMENT_TERMINATOR                            #Assignment
|   QUESTIONMARK text=STRING? expr? STATEMENT_TERMINATOR        #Print
|   ID '=' QUESTIONMARK prompt=STRING? STATEMENT_TERMINATOR     #Input
;

NEWLINE: [\r\n] -> skip;
STATEMENT_TERMINATOR: ';' -> skip;
```

Also you can use `channel(HIDDEN)` command for these terminals.

Onward In Visitor (or Listener) you can access to the last statement by such way: `context.stat(context.stat.Length - 1)`

Comment: Thats why I ask the pros! :-) Thank you!